# IntelliJ can't find package imported via New Module feature, then automatically deletes import statement?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, import

I'm new to the IntelliJ project.  Here is my IntelliJ version info:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1
Build #IU-172.3544.35, built on July 31, 2017
Subscription is active until April 3, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b6 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 3.13.0-128-generic
```

I am running on Linux Ubuntu 14.04.

I had two completely separate projects.  I wanted to import code that resides in a JAR file from the first project into the second.

I tried using the "New Module -> Import from existing sources" option, and that did add the entire first project to my second project's source structure.  But I still can't import classes found in the JAR file that are used successfully by the first project, into the second project.  When I try, IntelliJ gives me the "*cannot resolve symbol*" error.  More annoyingly, after a certain length of time *or* when I try to compile the project it **automatically deletes the import statement(s)**.  (Is this the "auto-remove unused imports" feature biting me here?)

For example, the following import statement can be found in the first project and is considered valid by IntelliJ (no warnings or errors):

```
import com.github.**messenger4j**.MessengerPlatform;
```

But when I try to use that very same import in a file in my second project I get the "cannot resolve symbol" error for "**messenger4j** and the import statement gets auto-deleted at some point.  Note, the file that I'm trying use the import statement in is a **groovy** source file that resides in the second project, in case that matters.

Also, if I look at the repo repository that IntelliJ maintains in the "~/.m2" directory, I do see the JAR file.  Here you can see that I can successfully navigate the ".m2" repository tree to the messenger4j package:

```
/home/user9/.m2/repository/com/github/messenger4j$
```

How can I properly import and use the **github.com.messenger4j** jar file in my second project?

**UPDATE**: The following appears to give me access to the desired JAR that resides in the "~/.m2" directory:

```
File -> 
Project Structure -> 
Dependencies (tab) -> 
"+" sign in right hand border ->
Library
```

I then see the JAR file in the library list and by adding it, I no longer get the unresolved symbol error.  **Is this the correct way to use IntelliJ/Maven to use an external JAR file?**

Comment: Of course you can always import the jar manually but I think use maven is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the correct way to use IntelliJ/Maven to use an external JAR file?

No, this is not the Maven way.

If both projects use Maven they both have a POM file defining a couple of things. Let's say you have the following setup:

**Project A**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

</project>
```

**Project B**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

</project>
```

If you want to use classes from project A in Project B, you need to add project A as a dependency of Project B. Change the POM file of project B to:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

But that's not the only thing. For project B to use project A, Maven needs to know where it can find it. This is solved by installing project A in the local Maven repository by running the `mvn clean install` command in the root directory of project A.

After that, IntelliJ's Maven will be able to find the dependency without you manually importing project A.

Comment: Thanks.  Is that how you would do it with IntelliJ?  Or is there an IntelliJ IDE feature that does approximately the same thing?

Comment: @RobertOschler This is the way, yes. Maven integration is one-way in IntelliJ. You are able to add libraries with IntelliJ, but they are never written to the POM file. You need to do this yourself.

Comment: Thanks.  Any tips for Gradle?  Project A is Maven and Project B, the project that needs to access the JAR found in Project A, is in Gradle.  This is the situation I have inherited at work.

Comment: I know you can use the Maven local repository for Gradle as well.

Answer (score 2):

File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies -> Choose your dependency and change it from "Runtime" to "Compile"